# How to make rails admin navigation label link start with https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, rails-admin

I wanna use `https` for my website, I configured nginx properly, add set `HOST` env variable to `https` domain in `application.yml` file then everything is working fine, but my rails admin left navigation label link still starts with `http`, even I can't find any config file to do that. I saw that rails admin navigation link is `absolute link`, so I think there must be a place to get host by rails admin.

How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit your production.rb file and add this

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

You can even exclude addresses if all you want is the admin urls to redirect to the https version

```
  config.ssl_options = {
    redirect: {
      exclude: ->(request) {
        request.path =~ /app/
      }
    }
  }
```

For more options go to 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want any URL to convert into secure url you can pass `{ :secure => true }` in url option.